# On Hadoop Network System Call

Tags: networking, hadoop, jvm, system-calls

1. Since `Socket` is used in hadoop src, guess it's TCP connections to send/recv messages and files, right?
2. How JVM translate these `Socket` instances to Linux system calls, is that socket/send, or select/poll?
3. If it's all about select/poll, I still can get ip/port through relative socket system calls, right?
4. When I collect all the sys_calls during a terasort (1 master, 3 slaves), I got rare connect/accept/socket sys_calls, and they are without any LAN ip in the sockaddr struct (either 0 or strange ones, IPv4). There are bunches of select/poll sys_calls, is that reasonable?

Answer (score 0):

1. you could use "netstat --tcp -n" commands to check current tcp connection. i guess Hadoop should use TCP.
2. you may need use strace  to start your Hadoop JVM. The strace will print system calls used by the running application. Usual application use sys_poll to check connection FD's status and use read/write or sendto/recvfrom syscall to receive transmit packet.
3. ?
4. Right, these system call is only called once during connection setup through sys_socket system call, then application does many polls, transmit or receives operation on that socket.